# Is it possible to use Symmetric Keys within a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, view, encryption-symmetric

I have View which I want to alter with a condition. But I want to use symmetric key inside the view. Below is my code:

```
create view dbo.[Test_view]
select

t.med_id,
t.medicine_name,
case when 
    t.taxo_id like '%include%' then '1'
    else '0' end as 'Taxo_number' ----The taxo_id is encrypted column
from dbo.Meds t
```

I want to include one more column in the view 'Taxo_number' which is based on taxo_id column that is encrypted with symmetric key.

```
My key is: OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [Test_Key] DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [Test_Cert]
```

Is there a way to include this key in the 'View' script? Pls help!

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. Here's a POC:

```
use tempdb;
go

create symmetric key [mykey] 
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256  
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SouperSecretz>789'
go

create table dbo.Secrets (
    Secret varbinary(400)
)
go

create view dbo.openSecrets
as
    select cast(decryptbykey(Secret) as varchar(200)) as OpenSecret
    from dbo.Secrets
go

open symmetric key [mykey] 
    DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'SouperSecretz>789'
go

insert into dbo.Secrets (Secret)
values (ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('myKey'), 'asdfasdf'));


select *
from dbo.openSecrets;

close symmetric key [mykey];

select *
from dbo.openSecrets;
```

In this demo, I'm creating:

- a symmetric key
- a table that will hold data encrypted by that key
- a view on top of that table that does the decryption

Of the two selects I do against the view, one of them has the key open and the other doesn't. The former reveals the plaintext while the latter returns `null`.

So, as long as you have the key open in your session, you should be able to see the plaintext data. And if not, you'll (successfully) get a `null` for that column.